# How to Copy, paste a section in Word document without even opening the document using Python

Tags: python, docx

I have a word document of more than 5000 pages and is it possible to copy paste an entire section within in the document using python? I want this to be done in the background as opening the word document with more than 5000 pages is extremely slow even in draft mode

1. Script should prompt the user to choose the document

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import docx

root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("Word Documents", "*.docx")])

doc = docx.Document(file_path)
```

2. Script should prompt the user to select the section / heading in the document -- User responds only the section/heading number like 3.1.2.1

No idea on how to perform this

This should copy the entire section 3.1.2.1 and paste it below in the same document. So, the new pasted section will become 3.1.2.2

Comment: What do you mean by "without opening it"? You don't have to open it _in Word_ (nor should you), but you'll have to open it in _Python_.

Comment: Yes, Python can open the document in the background - I do not want to open it manually as it causes slowness in each action in the word document

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but can you try to use https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/   library to read the Word document and do it.

- The script searches the document for the section number entered as input and copies it.
- The new section is inserted below the original section, and its section number is incremented.
- The updated document is saved to the same file.